# X509 information with only private key file

Tags: openssl

I would like to know will there be any way to extract X509 information such as CommonName, Subject, Issuer, etc. from a private key file alone.

I know is it possible to fetch the certificate information (X509) from a public key file but I want to know is it possible to achieve the same via private key file.

The requirement for me is that I will be having a private key file without any public key information in it.

if it’s also possible, how to do it via OpenSSL API?

Comment: How do you extract x509 information from public key? See, when you generate a keypair you don't include any data more than the modulus size and optional encryption. They're just keys, not certificates.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. Private keys contain no information about certificates.